# How to convert Object.keys(X) to typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Chips.jsx

```
Chips.propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string,
    color: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.keys(Chips.colors)),
}
```

What will be the type of color props in typescript?

```
interface ChipsProps{
    className?: string,
    **color?: ??** 
}
```

The type of Chips.color is Record<string,string>.
Here, Record is of type:

```
  GRASS_GREEN: "grass_green",
  DONE_GREEN: "done-green",
  BRIGHT_GREEN: "bright-green",
```

Comment: That’ll be `keyof type of Chips.color`

Comment: If you want to get more help from the typescript's auto completion, use const assertion(ex. `as const`)